# Is it possible to combine HotKey and mouse click to select a menu item?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have an app that requires multiple key press AND mouse click at same time, in order to access a menu item.
I need to automate this part and I tried

```
pyautogui.click(image1.x, image1.y) AND pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'shft', 'alt')
```

I also tried

```
            pyautogui.keyDown('shift')  # hold down the shift key
            pyautogui.keyDown('alt')  # hold down the shift key
            pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')  # hold down the shift key
            pyautogui.click(image1.x, image1.y)
```

I see click operation but not with keys. I need click and keys pressed action at the same time.
Note that I have access to window.
Is there any other tool or package I can use for this?
Is there a way to for me to see what key press is actually happening or events?
Thank you for help

Comment: can this be made such that once the hotkey combination is pressed by the user then the click happens

Answer (score 0):

Does the code also releases the pressing of the buttons? It seems right to me for the most part, but I don't know if I am getting this right.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of click, I used first MoveTo and then click command. 
Technically click(x,y) should do both but breaking my work in two solved my problem.